# Untrusted connection warning even though my site has a valid certificate

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I redirect all URLs on my website to `https://www.mysite.tld/…` to ensure the connection is secure. But my browser shows an “untrusted connection” warning.

My site has a valid certificate. When I access my website via `http://mysite.tld/` (without `www.`), no warning is shown.

How can I enable even the `www.mysite.tld` domain to work with HTTPS without warning, or at least redirect all the URLs to `mysite.tld` (without `www.`)?

Comment: You will need to purchase a certificate for both `https://yoursite.com` and `https://www.yoursite.com`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to mention an important fact that had been stated only in a comment: mysite.tld works, while www.mysite.tld gives warning. When you forget to include such an important piece of info initially, feel free to edit later! I added [tag:mod_rewrite] tag to indicate you’re looking for help with writing a redirection rule using mod_rewrite Apache module. “Hello”, “please help”, “thanks” and other such phrases are frowned upon here, they don’t add any info.

Answer (score 0):

If your site is displaying untrusted connection warning the domain is blocked by google. ask google groups how to trust your site.

Comment: It works fine when input url is https : //mysite. I dont know much about rewrite rule. Is there any rule which can redirect all url input to https : //mysite??

Comment: are you purchased ssl from hosting provider... then do first.

Answer (score 0):

You must purchase ssl certificate, or you can try www.freessl.com

Comment: If you are expert in rewrite rule could you please provide me the rule which redirects url  https:// www.example.com) to  https:// example.com

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

Answer (score 0):

The two most common reasons for this warning are:

- The website is using a self-signed/free SSL certificate.
- The website is using a private SSL certificate but it is missing a CA (Certificate Authority) certificate.

The solution in the first case is to purchase a private SSL certificate which is issued for the specific domain by a trusted authority.

The solution in the second case is to have the SSL certificate reinstalled with the correct CA bundle. The CA bundle is provided by the SSL vendor and should be included in the private SSL package.

To redirect http to https just copy and paste the below code to your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

**Edit:**
To redirect to `https://example.com` use the below one.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,QSA,L]
```

the second line checks whether HTTPS is on

Comment: Thank you sir for the detailed explanation. The problem here is when I use https: //mysite, it works fine but when i use https: //www it show warning. Could you please provide me the code that redirects all the url input to https: //mysite. Thank you